# How to check device plateform between phone & tablet in phonegap for set screen orientation?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I use pg-plugin-screen-orientation : https://github.com/their/pg-plugin-screen-orientation

**How to check device plateform between phone & tablet in phonegap for set screen orientation ?**

I develop with **sencha touch**

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this: http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/demos/Ext.os.is/viewer.html

If you would like to check the device type, you can use something like this:

```
if(Ext.os.is.Phone)
{
    console.log('Phone');
}
else if(Ext.os.is.Tablet)
{
    console.log('Tablet');
}
else
{
    console.log('Others');
}
```

More on this:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.os

Comment: If I check the device type in sencha touch so in AndroidManifest.xml No need to put code it.?